# Find smallest $k$ such that the given trigonometric functions are $O(x^k)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, notation, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I feel like I do not quite grasp the concept of Big O Notation. From my understanding, if $f(x) = O(g(x))$ then $f(x)$ is at most $g(x)$ multiplied by some constant C, which makes decent sense to me. However, I become very confused when trying to apply the constant.

For my homework in mathematical analysis, my teacher assigned three functions such that $f(x)=O(x^k)$ and told us to find the smallest possible k in each instance. I think I was able to solve the first one but am unable to make any head way on the other two. They are as follows:

1. $\sin(x^2)$
2. $1-\cos(x^2)$
3. $\tan(x^3)$

My problem in understanding these questions is pretty fundamental and I feel that once I get one I will be able to solve the others. Any help is appreciated, but I'm not really looking for plain answers with no explanations.

As stated previously, I think I was able solve the first one and here is my logic behind it:

1. I broke $\sin(u)$ into its taylor series, such that: $$sin(u)=u-\frac{u^3}{3!}+\frac{u^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
2. I substitued $x^2$ for $u$ such that: $$\sin(x^2)=u-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n-2}}{(2n-1)!}$$
3. From here, I followed a procedure in my book (which could be wrong!) such that $\sin(x^2)=O(x^{4n})$, and, therefore, $4n$ is the smallest value k for the circumstance

Any help, whether it be corrections, hints, or solutions are quite welcome.

Comment: I'm also get confused with big o notation, but for the first one, wouldn't $k=0$? You have $|$sin$(x^2)|\leq 1=x^0$

Comment: This makes sense, but I think it's too trivial. . .In my notes there is an example in which sin(x)=O($x^{2n+1}$). I really don't understand the notation

Comment: Just a side: Big o involves a limit $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to a$. Usually $a=0$ or $a=\infty$ and is not specified. I'm not sure if you knew since it wasn't included in the question, but maybe it helps. For example, with the second function, $|1-$cos$(x^2)|\leq 1+|$cos$(x^2)|\leq 2$, so $1-cos$(x^2)\neq O(1)$, but $1-cos$(x^2)=O(x)$ since $2<x$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: @user153582 I believe $x\to 0$ here, otherwise 1,2) are trivial and 3) makes no sense because of singularities.

Comment: @user153582 But then the instruction to find "smallest possible $k$" is not quite meaningful... should be the largest possible.

Comment: You should replace the first term $u$ by $x^2$ in your point 2.